# not able to create cocoa touch class in the swift package instead it is creating .h and .m files

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, package, swift-package-manager

i have created a package in my project and when i try to create a cocoa touch class to create a view controller class, it is instead creating myclass.h and myclass.m file so the question is whether it is possible to create a UIViewcontroller subclass in swift package or not

Comment: Any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

The best workaround I found is

1. Add the Swift Package as a local dependency to a sample app
2. Create Cocoa touch file inside the app
3. Drag, move it in the Sources/Module/ folder of the Swift package